# Is it possible to recover data in Google Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, logging, google-cloud-datastore, database-restore

We are running application on Google App Engine platform. As a result of bug we've occasionaly (in a short period of time) deleted large number of Google Datastore entities (all of the same kind) in our production application. It there any way to recover deleted entities? May be Google keeps logs? May be they not physically delete entities but marks them as deleted? What would be the best way if any?

Comment: I dont think that this is possible. You need to care about backups by yourself.

Comment: not possible to my knowledge. Once it's gone, it's gone.

Answer (score 0):

As it's been pointed out in comments, no it's impossible. Google doesn't automatically backs your data up (imagine the size those logs would be!).

if you didn't do your backup yourself, it's over for your data unfortunately